# How to seek audio with MediaSource and continue playing?

Tags: javascript, typescript, html5-audio, media-source

I am currently trying to implement an audio player for my Angular web application following [a tutorial on Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/mse/seamless-playback) and also some help I've found on " [Can't seek video when playing from MediaSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40069244/cant-seek-video-when-playing-from-mediasource) ".

The big difference in my case though is that I want to *stream* the audio chunk-wize such that the user does not have to download the entire file in order to listen to it right away.

Listening to a track from the start to the beginning is already working as I am just downloading byte-chunks from the server and simply append each chunk to the `SourceBuffer` as they arrive.

However, I am not able to implement the "seek" functionality.

I do not quite understand how to handle this on the client. At the moment I only work with mp3 files. I cannot find *any* example where [`seeking`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/seeking_event) is explained.

I know that setting `currentTime` of an `audio` element will trigger a `seeking` event according to the [Media Events doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events).
We have:

```js
this.audioObj = document.createElement('audio');
```

and a setter:

```js
public seekTo(seconds) {
  this.logger.debug(`seekTo ${seconds.toFixed(2)} seconds`);
  // Setting currentTime will cause a "seeking" event to be emitted.
  this.audioObj.currentTime = seconds;
}
```

I *think* that I have to load new data before I set `currentTime` and append it to the `sourceBuffer`. However, this simply cannot work for obvious reasons.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've set the duration, you should be able to set the currentTime but there will be nothing to play. You can use the currentTime to inform your chunk fetcher which portion of the file you need and append it so the media element can continue to play.

Note that when using mp3, the SourceBuffer will be operating in `sequence` mode since there are no timestamps, which means that if you just blindly append bytes they will not be at the correct point in time - I believe you need to set `timestampOffset` to the relevant time for the frame in question (I haven't tried this myself).

Comment: I was able to solve this issue by setting `SourceBuffer#timestampOffset` as you suggested. Now the `currentTime` does have the offset included and I can display this information in my player correctly.